# Run a PyCharm script from Terminal

Tags: pycharm

I have developed a project in Python 3 using Pycharm, and have been running it from within PyCharm (on a Mac). Everything works in Debug and Run.

I now want to run it in Terminal, outside PyCharm. I cd to the main directory of my project (where my .py files are) and activate the virtual environment with:

```
source <path to my venv folder>
```

However, when I run my python file with:

```
python3 myfile.py
```

It fails on the first import with e.g. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named tensorflow. The import command in this case is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

What should I be doing to run a PyCharm project from a Terminal session? N.B. I still want to be able to run it in PyCharm for debugging etc.

Thanks for any help.

Julian

Comment: PyCharm does not use your global package folder. Therefore packages installed via PyCharm aren't avaialable globally. Try installing TensorFlow in your global package directory. Or add the PyCharm-Module dir to your path.

Comment: Are you sure you set up your project in PyCharm correctly? It looks like your dependencies are not installed in the virtual environment, which makes me believe you set up PyCharm to use your system python directly, rather than using venv.

Comment: Konrad, I have checked my PyCharm setup and the venv seems to be set up as I would expect. It does not inherit global site-packages. I have created several Pycharm projects and they all require packages to be installed. mortom123, I could install Tensorflow globally, but why isn't it finding it from the venv? How can I get more info about what it is doing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was incorrect to type:

```
source <path to my venv folder>
```

to activate my virtual environment.

I tried cd to the venv directory, then:

```
source bin/activate
```

It now works. I don't know why. The original source venv didn't give any error.